# Parallel regression assumption

Tags: ordinal-data, quadratic-form, ordered-logit

In ordinal logit models, do I violate the parallel regression assumption if I include a quadratic term for a nonlinear relationship? Because then it would mean that the coefficients are not in the same direction for each ordinal category.

Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 6):

The parallel regression assumption (aka proportional regression assumption) in ordinal logistic regression says that the coefficients that describe the odds of being in the lowest category vs. all higher categories of the response variable are the same as those that describe the odds between the second lowest category and all higher categories, etc.

This is a consequence of how the ordered logistic model is defined. It is a consequence of the fact that there is only one set of coefficients for all odds you're modeling (lowest category vs. all higher, second lowest vs. all higher, etc). *If you include quadratic or non-linear terms then it is still the same set of coefficients for all odds you're modeling*. So, whether or not you add quadratic or non-linear terms has nothing to do with the parallel regression assumption.